# Full Dynamic HTML Table Hover Events Not Working

Tags: jquery, html, css, html-table

I am attempting to create a table without any previous information in the HTML document.

In this example below I would like to have a table created, then a header, and row. Assume the table layout in the real program to be in sets of `<tr><th>` and `<tr><td>` (Header row and then cell row).

I would like to then be able to hover on any cell row and have it color both that cell row and the previous header row.

The issue is that the methods previously used don't seem to work if the table is entirely dynamically allocated.

```js
var statTable = $('<table>', {"id": "statTable", "class": "statTable"});

$("#tableCreate").click(function() {
  $("#newDiv").append(statTable);
  $("#statTable").append("<tbody>");
  $(this).prop('disabled', true);
});

$("#setCreate").click(function() {
  $("tbody").append($("<tr>")).append($("<th>").text("HEADER"));
  $("tbody").append($("<tr>")).append($('<td>').text("TESTING..."));
});

$("#statTable tr").hover(function() {
  $(this).prev().find('th').removeClass('green');
  $(this).prev().find('th').addClass('red');
}, function() {
  $(this).prev().find('th').removeClass('red');
  $(this).prev().find('th').addClass('green');
});
```

```css
td {
  border: 1px solid black;
}

th {
  background-color: green;
  border: 1px solid black;
}

.red {
  background-color: red !important;
}

.green {
  background-color: green !important;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<html>

<button id="tableCreate">make table </button>
<button id="setCreate">add set</button>

<div id="newDiv">
</div>
</html>
```

Comment: You can use CSS for this, why do you want to use `.hover` for this?

Comment: @Abinthaha I thought you are only able to style next elements using the + CSS operator as there is no previous operator. If this isn't the case please let me know what CSS I would need to write.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because when you bind an event to an element it has to exist.

There is a trick to do it though. Instead of binding an event to an element you can bind to document and trigger it only on specific element.

Also you have a minor mistake while appending `th` and `td` to `tr`. I fixed it and now it works properly.

**Here is an working example**

```js
var statTable = $('<table>', {"id": "statTable", "class": "statTable"});

$("#tableCreate").click(function() {
  $("#newDiv").append(statTable);
  $("#statTable").append("<tbody>");
  $(this).prop('disabled', true);
});

$("#setCreate").click(function() {
  $("tbody").append($("<tr>").append($("<th>").text("HEADER")));
  $("tbody").append($("<tr>").append($('<td>').text("TESTING...")));
});

$(document).on({
  mouseenter: function() {
    $(this).prev().find('th').removeClass('green');
    $(this).prev().find('th').addClass('red');
  },
  mouseleave: function() {
    $(this).prev().find('th').removeClass('red');
    $(this).prev().find('th').addClass('green');
  }
}, "#statTable tr");
```

```css
td {
  border: 1px solid black;
}

th {
  background-color: green;
  border: 1px solid black;
}

.red {
  background-color: red !important;
}

.green {
  background-color: green !important;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<html>

<button id="tableCreate">make table </button>
<button id="setCreate">add set</button>

<div id="newDiv">
</div>

</html>
```

Comment: I just figured that out when seeing the other answer from @dipmala Works like a charm, thanks

Answer (score 1):

Use `on` instead of `hover` for dynamic content:

```
$('#newDiv').on({
mouseenter: function () {
     $(this).prev().find('th').removeClass('green');
     $(this).prev().find('th').addClass('red');
},
mouseleave: function () {
    $(this).prev().find('th').removeClass('red');
    $(this).prev().find('th').addClass('green');
}
}, "#statTable tr");
```

Comment: The events aren't triggering and if the `#newDiv` is used for the `.on()` than the `$(this).prev()` will be referring to incorrect elements, no?

Comment: @SeniorFluffie It will be okay. it wil be reffering to current `tr`. `#newDiv` is container for attaching to.

Answer (score 1):

You need to bind the click event with following way and need to bind it for td

```
$(document).on("mouseenter", "#statTable td", function() {
  alert('in'); // add your logic
});

$(document).on("mouseleave", "#statTable td", function() {
  alert('out');
});
```